# unable to deploy play 2.1 scala app to heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.1

when I try to deploy my play scala 2.1 app to heroku I get the following error:

> ```
>   [info] Wrote /tmp/build_36s2qu6pn5i6k/target/scala-2.10/get2play_2.10-1.0.pom
>   [info] Packaging /tmp/build_36s2qu6pn5i6k/target/scala-2.10/get2play_2.10-1.0-sources.jar ...
>   [info] Done packaging.
>   [info] Generating Scala API documentation for main sources to /tmp/build_36s2qu6pn5i6k/target/scala2.10/api...
>   /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in spawn': command='/app/slug-compiler/lib/../../tmp/buildpacks/scala/bin/compile /tmp/build_36s2qu6pn5i6k /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache' exit_status=0 out='' at=timeout elapsed=902.47056889534 (Utils::TimeoutError)
>
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:53:in `loop'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:53:in `block in spawn'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:48:in `popen'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:48:in `spawn'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:37:in `block in compile'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:35:in `fork'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:35:in `compile'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:526:in `block in run_buildpack'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:122:in `log'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:763:in `log'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:525:in `run_buildpack'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:103:in `block in timeout'
>   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:103:in `rescue in timeout'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:98:in `timeout'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:119:in `block in compile'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:122:in `log'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:763:in `log'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:118:in `compile'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:86:in `block in <main>'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:534:in `block in lock'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `call'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `run'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:534:in `lock'
>   from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:67:in `<main>'
> ```
>
> !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.x - scala app

everything worked till yesterday. there were no big code changes.

has anyone an idea what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem with play 2.0.4

Comment: for me it looks more and more like a heroku prob. reverted to a revision that worked definitly and have the same problem. will try to contact someone from heroku now.

Comment: Today the problem is gone.

Comment: i opened a ticket on friday and they said they found the bug and fixed it. the log shows that the deployment continues further than before but i still got the same error.